# Big table in beamer

Tags: tikz-pgf, tables, beamer, longtable, tikz-trees

I have a big table that does not fit in the slides with Beamer, i write this :

```
 \documentclass[10pt]{beamer}
 \usetheme{CambridgeUS} % theme
 \usepackage{tikz}
 \begin{document}
 \begin{frame}
 \begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|}
 \hline 
 % line 1
 & 

\begin{tikzpicture} [every fit/.style={ellipse,draw,red,inner sep=-2pt},scale=0.5]  

  \node(a1){a}
  child{node(b1){b}}
  child{node{b} child{node{b}} child{node{a}}};
 \end{tikzpicture} 

  & 

\begin{tikzpicture} [every fit/.style={ellipse,draw,red,inner sep=-2pt},scale=0.5]  

 \node{a}
  child{node(a2){a} child{node{b}}}
  child{node{b} child{node{b}} child{node{a}}};

 \end{tikzpicture} 

\\ \hline


%line 2 
$a$ & 1 & 1  \\ \hline

%line 3 
$b$ & 2 & 2  \\ \hline

%line 4 

\begin{tikzpicture} [every fit/.style={ellipse,draw,red,inner sep=-2pt},scale=0.5]  

 \node{a}
 child{node{a}};

 \end{tikzpicture} 

& 0 & 0  \\ \hline

 %line 4 

 \begin{tikzpicture} [every fit/.style={ellipse,draw,red,inner sep=-2pt},scale=0.5]  

 \node{a}
 child{node{b}};

 \end{tikzpicture} 

& 0 & 1  \\ \hline

 %line 5 

\begin{tikzpicture} [every fit/.style={ellipse,draw,red,inner sep=-2pt},scale=0.5]  

 \node{b}
 child{node{a}};

 \end{tikzpicture} 

& 0 & 0  \\ \hline

 %line 6 

 \begin{tikzpicture} [every fit/.style={ellipse,draw,red,inner sep=-2pt},scale=0.5]  

 \node{b}
 child{node{a}};

 \end{tikzpicture} 

& 0 & 0  \\ \hline

  \begin{tikzpicture} [every fit/.style={ellipse,draw,red,inner sep=-2pt},scale=0.5]  

 \node{b}
 child{node{a}}child{node{a}} ;

 \end{tikzpicture} 

& 0 & 0  \\ \hline

 \begin{tikzpicture} [every fit/.style={ellipse,draw,red,inner sep=-2pt},scale=0.5]  

 \node{b}
 child{node{b}}child{node{a}} ;

 \end{tikzpicture} 

& 1 & 1  \\ \hline



  $\vdots$ & $\vdots$ & $\vdots$  \\ \hline


   \begin{tikzpicture} [every fit/.style={ellipse,draw,red,inner sep=-2pt},scale=0.5]  

  \node(a1){a}
  child{node(b1){b}}
  child{node{b} child{node{b}} child{node{a}}};
 \end{tikzpicture}  & 1 & 0  \\ \hline

   \begin{tikzpicture} [every fit/.style={ellipse,draw,red,inner sep=-2pt},scale=0.5]  

 \node{a}
  child{node(a2){a} child{node{b}}}
  child{node{b} child{node{b}} child{node{a}}};

 \end{tikzpicture}   & 0 & 1  \\ \hline
 $\vdots$ & $\vdots$ & $\vdots$  \\ \hline
 \end{tabular}

 \end{frame}
 \end{document}
```

The result is given by the picture below
[image]

Any idea will be appreciated to solve this size issue.

Comment: Since this is beamer, it's intended for a presentation. There the table might be hard to digest on the fly even if you solve the size problem. Perhaps imagine a slide format that might be easier to read - maybe showing just a part of the table will be enough to make your lecture point.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get the content onto the slide, I rotated it 90 degrees and reduced the space around each cell and used a smaller font.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{beamer}
\usetheme{CambridgeUS} % theme
\usepackage{tikz}
\long\def\aa{\relax}%
\long\def\ab{\begin{tikzpicture} [every fit/.style={ellipse,draw,red,inner sep=-2pt},scale=0.5]  
\node{a}
child{node{a}};
\end{tikzpicture} }
\long\def\ac{\begin{tikzpicture} [every fit/.style={ellipse,draw,red,inner sep=-2pt},scale=0.5]  
\node{a}
child{node{b}};
\end{tikzpicture} }
\long\def\ad{\begin{tikzpicture} [every fit/.style={ellipse,draw,red,inner sep=-2pt},scale=0.5]  
\node{b}
child{node{a}};
\end{tikzpicture} }
\long\def\ae{ \begin{tikzpicture} [every fit/.style={ellipse,draw,red,inner sep=-2pt},scale=0.5]  
\node{b}
child{node{a}};
\end{tikzpicture} }
\long\def\af{  \begin{tikzpicture} [every fit/.style={ellipse,draw,red,inner sep=-2pt},scale=0.5]  
\node{b}
child{node{a}}child{node{a}} ;
\end{tikzpicture} }
\long\def\ag{ \begin{tikzpicture} [every fit/.style={ellipse,draw,red,inner sep=-2pt},scale=0.5]  
\node{b}
child{node{b}}child{node{a}} ;
\end{tikzpicture} }
\long\def\ah{  \begin{tikzpicture} [every fit/.style={ellipse,draw,red,inner sep=-2pt},scale=0.5]  
\node(a1){a}
child{node(b1){b}}
child{node{b} child{node{b}} child{node{a}}};
\end{tikzpicture}}
\long\def\ai{\begin{tikzpicture} [every fit/.style={ellipse,draw,red,inner sep=-2pt},scale=0.5]  
\node{a}
child{node(a2){a} child{node{b}}}
child{node{b} child{node{b}} child{node{a}}};
\end{tikzpicture} }
\long\def\ba{\begin{tikzpicture} [every fit/.style={ellipse,draw,red,inner sep=-2pt},scale=0.5]  
\node(a1){a}
child{node(b1){b}}
child{node{b} child{node{b}} child{node{a}}};
\end{tikzpicture}} 
\long\def\ca{\begin{tikzpicture} [every fit/.style={ellipse,draw,red,inner sep=-2pt},scale=0.5]  
\node{a}
child{node(a2){a} child{node{b}}}
child{node{b} child{node{b}} child{node{a}}};
\end{tikzpicture} }
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}\footnotesize
\renewcommand{\tabcolsep}{.05cm}
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|}\hline 
\aa&$a$&$b$&\ab&\ac&\ad&\ae&\af&\ag&$\hdots$&\ah&\ai&$\hdots$\\ \hline
\ba& 1 & 2 & 0 & 0 & 0 &  0&  0&  1&$\hdots$&  1&  0&$\hdots$\\ \hline
\ca& 1 & 2 & 0 & 1 & 0 &  0&  0&  1&$\hdots$&  0&  1&$\hdots$\\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{frame}
\tikzset{grow'=right}
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|}
\hline 
% line 1
& 
\begin{tikzpicture} [every fit/.style={ellipse,draw,red,inner sep=-2pt},scale=0.25]  
\node(a1){a}
child{node(b1){b}}
child{node{b} child{node{b}} child{node{a}}};
\end{tikzpicture} 
& 
\begin{tikzpicture} [every fit/.style={ellipse,draw,red,inner sep=-2pt},scale=0.25]  
\node{a}
child{node(a2){a} child{node{b}}}
child{node{b} child{node{b}} child{node{a}}};
\end{tikzpicture} 
\\ \hline
%line 2 
$a$ & 1 & 1  \\ \hline
%line 3 
$b$ & 2 & 2  \\ \hline
%line 4 
\begin{tikzpicture} [every fit/.style={ellipse,draw,red,inner sep=-2pt},scale=0.25]  
\node{a}
child{node{a}};
\end{tikzpicture} 
& 0 & 0  \\ \hline
%line 4 
\begin{tikzpicture} [every fit/.style={ellipse,draw,red,inner sep=-2pt},scale=0.25]  
\node{a}
child{node{b}};
\end{tikzpicture} 
& 0 & 1  \\ \hline
%line 5 
\begin{tikzpicture} [every fit/.style={ellipse,draw,red,inner sep=-2pt},scale=0.25]  
\node{b}
child{node{a}};
\end{tikzpicture} 
& 0 & 0  \\ \hline
%line 6 
\begin{tikzpicture} [every fit/.style={ellipse,draw,red,inner sep=-2pt},scale=0.25]  
\node{b}
child{node{a}};
\end{tikzpicture} 
& 0 & 0  \\ \hline
\begin{tikzpicture} [every fit/.style={ellipse,draw,red,inner sep=-2pt},scale=0.25]  
\node{b}
child{node{a}}child{node{a}} ;
\end{tikzpicture} 
& 0 & 0  \\ \hline
\begin{tikzpicture} [every fit/.style={ellipse,draw,red,inner sep=-2pt},scale=0.25]  
\node{b}
child{node{b}}child{node{a}} ;
\end{tikzpicture} 
& 1 & 1  \\ \hline
$\vdots$ & $\vdots$ & $\vdots$  \\ \hline
\begin{tikzpicture} [every fit/.style={ellipse,draw,red,inner sep=-2pt},scale=0.25]  
\node(a1){a}
child{node(b1){b}}
child{node{b} child{node{b}} child{node{a}}};
\end{tikzpicture}  & 1 & 0  \\ \hline
\begin{tikzpicture} [every fit/.style={ellipse,draw,red,inner sep=-2pt},scale=0.25]  
\node{a}
child{node(a2){a} child{node{b}}}
child{node{b} child{node{b}} child{node{a}}};
\end{tikzpicture}   & 0 & 1  \\ \hline
$\vdots$ & $\vdots$ & $\vdots$  \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Here is an alternate version where the orientation is the same as yours but the spacing has been tightened up.  With a check of the Tikz manual some of the duplicate parameters can be set globally to tighten up the code.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{beamer}
 \usetheme{CambridgeUS} % theme
 \usepackage{tikz}
 \begin{document}\tiny
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{.5}
 \begin{frame}
 \begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|}
 \hline 
 % line 1
 & 
\begin{tikzpicture} [every fit/.style={ellipse,draw,red,inner sep=-2pt},scale=0.25]  
  \node(a1){a}
  child{node(b1){b}}
  child{node{b} child{node{b}} child{node{a}}};
 \end{tikzpicture} 
  & 
\begin{tikzpicture} [every fit/.style={ellipse,draw,red,inner sep=-2pt},scale=0.25]  
 \node{a}
  child{node(a2){a} child{node{b}}}
  child{node{b} child{node{b}} child{node{a}}};
 \end{tikzpicture} 
\\ \hline
%line 2 
$a$ & 1 & 1  \\ \hline
%line 3 
$b$ & 2 & 2  \\ \hline
%line 4 
\begin{tikzpicture} [every fit/.style={ellipse,draw,red,inner sep=-2pt},scale=0.25]  
 \node{a}
 child{node{a}};
 \end{tikzpicture} 
& 0 & 0  \\ \hline
 %line 4 
 \begin{tikzpicture} [every fit/.style={ellipse,draw,red,inner sep=-2pt},scale=0.25]  
 \node{a}
 child{node{b}};
 \end{tikzpicture} 
& 0 & 1  \\ \hline
 %line 5 
\begin{tikzpicture} [every fit/.style={ellipse,draw,red,inner sep=-2pt},scale=0.25]  
 \node{b}
 child{node{a}};
 \end{tikzpicture} 
& 0 & 0  \\ \hline
 %line 6 
 \begin{tikzpicture} [every fit/.style={ellipse,draw,red,inner sep=-2pt},scale=0.5]  
 \node{b}
 child{node{a}};
 \end{tikzpicture} 
& 0 & 0  \\ \hline
  \begin{tikzpicture} [every fit/.style={ellipse,draw,red,inner sep=-2pt},scale=0.25]  
 \node{b}
 child{node{a}}child{node{a}} ;
 \end{tikzpicture} 
& 0 & 0  \\ \hline
 \begin{tikzpicture} [every fit/.style={ellipse,draw,red,inner sep=-2pt},scale=0.25]  
 \node{b}
 child{node{b}}child{node{a}} ;
 \end{tikzpicture} 
& 1 & 1  \\ \hline
  $\vdots$ & $\vdots$ & $\vdots$  \\ \hline
  \begin{tikzpicture} [every fit/.style={ellipse,draw,red,inner sep=-2pt},scale=0.25]  
  \node(a1){a}
  child{node(b1){b}}
  child{node{b} child{node{b}} child{node{a}}};
 \end{tikzpicture}  & 1 & 0  \\ \hline
  \begin{tikzpicture} [every fit/.style={ellipse,draw,red,inner sep=-2pt},scale=0.25]  
 \node{a}
  child{node(a2){a} child{node{b}}}
  child{node{b} child{node{b}} child{node{a}}};
 \end{tikzpicture}   & 0 & 1  \\ \hline
 $\vdots$ & $\vdots$ & $\vdots$  \\ \hline
 \end{tabular}
 \end{frame}
 \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: To complete your second solution, you may add `\tikzset{grow'=right}` to minimize the size of trees...

Comment: I modified the solution to show the effect of grow right beside the second solution.  Useful command.